# Unity Управление объектами сенсором

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на спрайт его можно было переместить с помощью сенсора. Но на касания реагируют и другие объекты. Как сделать так, чтобы на сенсор реагировал только объект на который я нажал?

```
public class Tahhii : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector3 touchPosition;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector3 direction;
    private float moveSpeed = 10f;


    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            touchPosition.z = 0;
            direction = (touchPosition - transform.position);
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y) * moveSpeed;

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в приведенном коде просто проверяете были ли какой-то инпут (тач в вашем случае) или нет. При этом этот тач весьма логично будет отрабатывать везде. Если хотите, чтобы этот тач отрабатывал только на том объекте, где висит этот скрипт, то проверьте, что координаты тача попадают конретно внутрь границ спрайта.

Сделать это не сложно - каждый спрайт рисуется компонентом `SpriteRenderer`, у которого вы можете получить границы с помощью [Renderer.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html). А дальше простой математикой узнайте входит ли координата тача (после преобразования `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position)`), внутрь прямоугольника, заданного `Renderer.bounds`. Имейте в виду, что координата z вашего тача и спрайта вас врядли интересует, по этому достаточно брать только x и y координату.

Comment: Можете скинуть как это будет выглядеть в самом коде? Не совсем понимаю что нужно сделать